# EDIT - Java while loop means events aren't called

Tags: java, click, mouse

So I've updated my code with the help of Cruncher, and now the clicker appears to work better. However whilst the while(pressed) loop is running, no other events are called & so it stays running.

public class Function implements NativeMouseListener {

```
private Robot robot;

private boolean pressed = false;

private boolean skip = false;

public Function()
{
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void repeatMouse()
{
    skip = true;
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    while (pressed)
    {
        System.out.println("pressed while loop " + pressed);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {

}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("GG");
    if (!(nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)) {
        System.out.println("Returned.");
        return;
    }
    if (!Native.get().getData().getEnabled())
    {
        System.out.println("Isn't enabled.");
        return;
    }

    pressed = true;
    repeatMouse();
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("released");
    if (!(nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)) {
        System.out.println("Returned 2");
        return;
    }
    if (!skip)
    {
        System.out.println("pressed " + pressed);
        pressed = false;
        System.out.println("pressed " + pressed);
    } else {
        skip = false;
    }

}
```

}

Any idea why the while loop would stop events from being called? Do I need to use multi threading or some of that jazz?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a guess, but you probably need to send a mouse up event at the beginning, then a bunch of mouse click events, and listen for a real mouse up event to stop.

Comment: @Cruncher "real" event? I'm using pressed and released and setting a boolean value. Is this wrong?

Comment: Can you let me know if the code provided in my answer was any help to you?

Comment: Very helpful, I am very grateful for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, your main method is not included in your code, but I assume it contains the following line(or similar):

`new Project()`

```
try {
    bot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while (pressed) {
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    //bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now let's look at this code. When this runs, pressed will be false at the beginning(presumably), and it will just exit and not be running on later clicks.

What you want to do is have your loop started when you register a click. Let's move it into another method

```
private void repeatMouse() {
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    while (pressed) {
        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's call it in your mouse down native hook

```
@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        pressed = true;
        System.out.println(pressed);
        repeatMouse();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
It appears your other problem is that after the first mouseRelease, the handler will get called from the native library. I have a potential solution for this.

First next to where you define your `pressed` variable, define a new `skipRelease`

```
boolean skipRelease = false;
```

Then before every call to mouseRelease, first set skipRelease to true. Then change your mouseRelease handler to the following

```
@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        if(skipRelease) {
            skipRelease = false;
            return;
        }
        pressed = false;
        System.out.println(pressed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Cruncher

Comment: However, how would you make the value false? Because if you use a bot to mousse release then the mouseRelease event will be called and therefore pressed will equal false. Right?

Comment: @Archie I was under the impression that the native calls wouldn't register from the robot. However if they do you need to be a little more clever. I'll edit my answer for a potential solution

Comment: you are very clever. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Archie On second thought, this may cause an acceleration effect if you're clicking for a long time. As each click will spawn another loop to click more. You'll need to use the same skipRelease method for mousePressed. I'm confident that you're able to figure it out from my example though :)

Comment: I will do! Thank you a bunch.

Comment: Cruncher, it appears that none of my events are being called whilst the while(pressed) loop is running. So that means it never gets cancelled. Any idea?